# Cluster Akka/Scala actors

Tags: scala, cluster-computing, actor, akka

can someone point me to the right content to learn about distributing Akka scala actors across several machines. I know that in the latest release of Akka there is location transparency. However, how does one go about deploying them and calling them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all documented here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/

When you configure your system according to the documentation you just have to start the application on each server and it should work.

```
akka {
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
  }
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    deployment {
      /sampleActor {
        remote = "akka://sampleActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2553"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These are the basic setting (taken from the docs) to enable remoting. This tells Akka to use remoting over the NettyRemoteTransport on host x port y and that /sampleActor runs on a remote system on the same machine but a different port.